# gradually reduce margin of body to 0 when screen is resized

Tags: css, margins

I'm looking at a page in 1920*1080 resolution. 
It's too much wide to spread all content from right to left, so I apply on body:

```
width: 77%;
background: #eee;
```

To get gray margins.

77%*1920 = 1478, so this means that I wouldn't want any margin once window size i below 1478px.

However, when window size is getting reduced towards 1478, I also want to reduce the margins.
For example: 1920-1478=442, half of it is 221, so when window size is 1478+221=1699 then margins should be about 88.5%, and not still in 77%.

So I need some calculation that will do this for any given size. It's a common practice isn't it? but how to do that?

```
body {

  width: 77%;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

   @media (max-width: 1700px) {
       body {
    width: 89%;
       }
  }

   @media (max-width: 1498px) {
       body {
    width: 100%;
       }
  }
```

Comment: It's not so clear: are you talking about right margin only or also left margin? the content is centered? at which viewport you want the margin be 0? and 221px? Please share some code

Comment: both margin, content centered, yes. margin should show as 77% and get reducded to 100% once we reach 1478 width. added some code

Comment: 77% is not the margin: in your example is the width of the body. your actual margin is 11.5% on the left and right: (100-77)/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you're actually trying to do is to give a `max-width: 1498px` to the container, so instead of applying the rule to the `body` use a container element (e.g. `<main>`) and give it a center alignment using `margin: 0 auto`

*See the example with a large resolution*

```css
body {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   background: #eee;
}
main {
   max-width: 1498px;
   background: #fff;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<main>

   main element
   
</main>
```